# Получить POST-данные с запроса (HTTP-сервер на сокетах на PHP)

Tags: php, http, сокет

Имеется код простейшего HTTP-сервера на сокетах на PHP, который нашёл в интернете. Для проверки решил попробовать выводить клиенту заголовки, которые он отправил. Всё работает. Но не могу понять как получить POST-данные, которые клиент отправил

```
<?php

$socket = stream_socket_server("tcp://0.0.0.0:8000", $errno, $errstr);

if (!$socket)
{
    die("$errstr ($errno)\n");
}

while (true)
{
    //формируем массив прослушиваемых сокетов:
    $read = $connects;
    $read[] = $socket;
    $write = $except = null;
    
    //ожидаем сокеты доступные для чтения (без таймаута)
    if (!stream_select($read, $write, $except, null))
    {
        break;
    }

    if (in_array($socket, $read))
    {
        //есть новое соединение
        $connect = stream_socket_accept($socket, -1); //принимаем новое соединение
        $connects[] = $connect; //добавляем его в список необходимых для обработки
        unset($read[array_search($socket, $read)]);
    }

    foreach ($read as $connect)
    {
        //обрабатываем все соединения
        $headers = "";
        while ($buffer = rtrim(fgets($connect)))
        {
            $headers .= $buffer . "\n";
        }
        fwrite($connect, "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\nContent-Type: text/plain\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n" . $headers);
        fclose($connect);
        unset($connects[array_search($connect, $connects)]);
    }
}

fclose($server);
```

Comment: У вас сокет-сервер, а не HTTP, придётся вам распарсивать входящие данные самостоятельно. Сокеты используются для потоков данных, и как следствие суперглобальных переменных типа $_POST в них не будет.

Comment: Я в курсе, что мне самому придётся распарсивать данные. Именно это я и пытаюсь сделать. Вопрос в том, как мне вообще вытащить POST-данные. Заголовки у меня получилось вытащить, а POST-данные - нет

Comment: А зачем? Может, проще сделать используя существующие библиотеки для обмена данными не изобретая велосипед? К примеру, [ReactPHP](https://reactphp.org/socket/) или [Ratchet](http://socketo.me/docs/websocket)